# Calling ExpGroupBy using jQuery for specific group

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007

I'm executing a click event using jQuery that should expand a certain group.

The code is:

```
01.<xsl:if test="not($hidedetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
02.  <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:CustomExpGroupBy(this);return false;">
03.    <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" name="{$altname}" style="vertical-align:middle" id="click-me" /></a>
04..
05..
06..
07.<xsl:otherwise>
08.  <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($fieldvalue) ,1033 ,'MMMM yyyy')" />
09.    <xsl:variable name="FilterVariable" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(substring($FilterMonthVariable,1,7)),1033,'MMMM yyyy')" />
10.<xsl:if test="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($fieldvalue) ,1033 ,'MMMM yyyy')=$FilterVariable">
11.Yes
12.<script type="text/javascript">$('#click-me').trigger('click');
13.</script> </xsl:if>
14.</xsl:otherwise>
```

So the code checks to see whether the group title matches the month parameter on the page. This works fine, and it displays "Yes" next to the correct month.

The problem is that the click expands the first group in my list. It triggers on the IF statement, but always expands the first group.

All of the code is in the group header template. Does anyone know how I can pass the correct group to expand to the CustomExpGroup function?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b26de8e1-c4df-406f-be50-f63f8c9e090a

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Once you flesh out your answer with a more detailed solution, please mark it as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success. Cheers~

Comment: I think the fellow only joined to ask this one question... Judging from his score, he's never been back.